# How to check to see if any of these strings exists inside another string and replace it if the answer is yes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to check to see if any of these 3 strings:

```
popularity
rating
views
```

exists in a string stored inside a variable called `theUrl`. If the answer is yes, then I want to replace that found string with the word `REPLACED`.

What would be an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
theUrl = theUrl.replace(/\b(popularity|rating|views)\b/g, 'REPLACED')
```

Answer (score 1):

The following way:

```
theUrl = theUrl.replace("popularity", "REPLACED").replace("rating", "REPLACED").replace("views", "REPLACED");
```